# Order chicken wing boxes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

You get a chicken wing boxes with either (3,8,20) items - is there a maximum number that you cannot buy and if so, which one?

Comment: no closed formula for these, once you have at least three items. If you identify three counts in a row, $n, n+1, n+2$ that you can buy, then all larger numbers are also possible, becuase you can just add some of the 3 boxes. Experiment.

Comment: Note:  the $20$ is irrelevant, as $20=8+4\times 3$.

Comment: See [coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) on wikipedia.  Then recognize the hint from lulu to reduce this problem to a well known one.

Comment: I know box of 20 is totally irrelevant, and I thought the answer is 13 - so I thought somebody has a clear reasoning for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first insight is that the box of 20 is distracting because it can be obtained by a box of 8s and 4 boxes of3s. Once you reach 3 consecutive numbers you know maximum is lower because you got box of 3s. Then total of 14 = 8 + 2*3 works, 15 = 5*3 works and also 16 = 2*8 works. However, 13 is not divisibly by 13, and the box of 8s only gets you either 11=8+1*3 or 14=8+2*3.